# Single-word replacement for "by definition"?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, software

> Software that is free is that which, by definition, has its full source code published.

I thought about *definitionally*, but after looking it up, it doesn't seem to be right.

Comment: That's quite a clumsy sentence all round. Why not just say, “Free software is defined as software whose full code is published”?

Comment: It was constructed around the purpose of exemplifying my question.

Answer (score 7):

Using *[defined](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/defined#Verb)* as a verb provides a simple answer to the grammatical issue the question raises.  However, the original statement and the suggested revisions of it are untrue.  It is not the case that free software is defined as software whose full code is published.  Although that is an intrinsic property of free software, it also is a property of [freeware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freeware).  In addition, some [proprietary software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proprietary_software) is distributed as published source code, under restrictions like copyrights and [non-disclosure agreements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-disclosure_agreement).  Refer to wikipedia's article about [Free Software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_Software) for a better definition (eg, “Free software is computer software that is distributed along with its source code, and is released under terms that guarantee users the freedom to study, adapt/modify, and distribute the software”) and for further distinguishing characteristics.

To connect “Free Software” and “published source code” with *by definition*, *is defined as*, or *definitionally* is wrong.  Instead say that having published code is an *[intrinsic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/intrinsic#Adjective)*, *[innate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/innate#Adjective)*, or *[inherent](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inherent#Adjective)* property of Free Software.

Comment: You’ll notice my rewrite fixed that.

Comment: @tchrist, you probably are correct, and my claim that “suggested revisions of it are untrue” could well be too broad.

Comment: @jwpat7 Point taken. What I meant to express was that the former set can be defined as a perfect subset of the latter one. Is there any word that expresses such meaning succinctly?

Comment: @user3025492, (a) I don't see the relevance of “a perfect subset”([1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_set),[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_set_property)).  Do you mean “a [*proper* subset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_subset#proper_subset)”? (b) Perhaps *[necessarily](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/necessarily#Adverb)* or *[of necessity](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/necessity)* are words like you want; eg: “Of necessity, full source code is publicly available for [open source software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-source_software)”.

Comment: @jwpat7 I think you missed the overall point of my question.

Answer (score 4):

Just use *define* as a verb.

> Software which is free is **defined** as having its full source code published without encumbrance or fees.

Comment: The OP example might be better written using `defined`.  Is there any equally-concise replacement of "by definition" in cases where one is using that fact that all foozles are defined to be woozles, and  a particular thing is not a woozle, to show that, "by definition", the thing cannot be a foozle?

Comment: NOpe. That wouldn't work, because that isn't the purpose of the sentence I have in mind... I mean, I don't think that this would work in a comma-delimited tangential clause. I guess I'm looking for something analogous to `inherently`. Do you see what I'm saying?

Answer (score 1):

- Free software, as such, necessarily has its full source code published.
- Software is free only if its full source code is published.

Answer (score 1):

These two sentences are not equivalent:

> By definition, free software has its full source code published.
>
> Free software is defined as software that has its full source code published.

The first one states a property of free software, which can be read directly from the definition, but there may be more to it. The second is saying what the definition *is*, and therefore would need to include the entire definition in order to be correct.

So, given the definition of free software from the referenced wikipedia article, one could say:

> By definition, free software provides the freedom to run the software for any purpose.

but, not

> Free software is defined as software one may run for any purpose.

because there is software that may be run for any purpose which is not technically free software.

So, assuming you rearrange the sentence a bit, there are some words you could use instead of the phrase 'by definition', such as 'always', 'obviously', 'clearly', 'inherently' and so on, but I don't know of any that also communicate the key piece of information that 'by definition' expresses. Namely, that you can glean this information directly from the definition without additional reasoning.

Comment: By definition, free software _has its full source code published_ . [necessary condition] //

Free software is defined as software that _has its full source code published_ . [definition] You might like this example from CDofAI: 'Circus performers are, by definition, delightful show-offs and risk takers.'

Answer (score 0):

If something similar to *definitionally* is desired, one option is *definitively*.

Comment: Is its meaning analogous to `inherently`?

Comment: @user3025492 From dictionary.com: **inherent:** existing in someone or something as a permanent and inseparable element, quality, or attribute; **definitive:** serving to define, fix, or specify definitely.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hyphenated word that I think is pretty powerful:

> **self-evident**:  *adjective* evident without proof or reasoning

To adapt it to your situation, perhaps:

> Software whose full source code published is considered, **self-evidently**, "free software."

*from m-w.com*